# Can I change the device brightness level with Corona SDK?

Tags: android, ios, coronasdk, brightness

I was wondering if it was possible to access the device brightness with the Corona SDK, either for iOS or Android. So far my search has turned up nothing.

The reason I'd like to do this is because Corona doesn't support backgrounding, meaning I'd like to fade out the visuals of my app after a certain period of interactivity while continuing to play sound (my app is an ambient noise app).

Thanks -

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a workaround, that would be to instead add a rectangle on top of the scene with alpha=0, and putting in place a timer or something that periodically checks the player activity, and triggers transition to makes the rectangle alpha go back to 1 (or your wanted 'fading level') whenever the player isn't active for some time.
Whenever the player is active again, just set the alpha back to 0.

Easy done with:

newRect: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newRect.html

timer.performWithDelay: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/performWithDelay.html

transition.to: https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/transition/to.html

Comment: Thanks Teddy - I had thought of this approach; however, on backlit displays, won't this burn the same amount of power as having the screen 'on' and displaying graphics?

Comment: I "think" smartphones are smart enough to reduce the consumption based on the brightness in general. I guess you would need to do a benchmark and compare it :)